# Saving selected keys in a dictionary to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary in python whose output is:

```
out = {
            "lower_level": {
                i: {"name": j["name"], "confidence": j["prob"], "by": 1}
                for i, j in level4.items()
            },
        }
```

This out dict is a list of Dict.

I want to save this dictionary in the form of following csv:

```
query category confidence
i     name      prob
```

How can i do this?

Sample out dict:

```
{'lower_level': {'television': {'name': '8k smart television', 'confidence': 0.9041114449501038, 'by': 1}}}
```

Desirec output in csv:

```
query      category      confidence
television 8k smart tv   0.9041
```

Comment: Can you add example of `out` to question?

Comment: added sample example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of nested dictionaries, add `query` and pass to DataFrame constructor, last remove column `by` and `rename` column name:

```
out = {'lower_level': {'television': {'name': '8k smart television', 
                                      'confidence': 0.9041114449501038, 'by': 1}}}
                    
df = (pd.DataFrame([{**{'query': k1},**v1} for k, v in out.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()])
        .drop('by', axis=1)
        .rename(columns={'name':'category'}))
print (df)
        query             category  confidence
0  television  8k smart television    0.904111
```

Or if possible generate list of dict from `level4`:

```
L = [{"query":i,"category":j["name"],"confidence":j["prob"]} for i,j in level4.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(L)

df.to_csv('file', index=False)
```

Comment: query and name is empty
.[[{'query': '', 'name': '', 'confidence': 0.9041114449501038, 'by': 1}]

Comment: @PrateekSingh - Added to answer, for me working well.